# Can you output your custom exception message but not the default as well in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to create exception handling for opening a file in ruby. I have tried to use the raise and rescue method but all types have either shown the custom and the default(instead of just the custom) or have errored out completely. [My attempted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epTd3.png)

[output showing custom one bottom but default on top I want to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbJBb.png)

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own. Also please post text, not images of text, or links to images of text.

Comment: You're calling out to the system--it will have its own output (likely to `stderr`).

Comment: Fixed it, I just need to put the system call after the raise statement

Answer (score 1):

It's because `system` doesn't raise an exception, it just has [varying return values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> `system` returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for non zero exit status. Returns `nil` if command execution fails. An error status is available in `$?`.

So you can see that it isn't Ruby printing the error message, it's the `open` command. It's easy to test in your shell:

```
$ open bar
The file /Users/foo/bar does not exist.
$ echo $?
1
```

Confirm in Ruby:

```
system 'open bar'
The file /Users/foo/bar does not exist.
=> false
puts $?
pid 9610 exit 1
=> nil
```

So there's nothing to `rescue` because there's no exception ever raised. You have to evaluate the return value of `system` or the exit code of the process (`$?`) to make a determination as to the success or failure of your call to `system`.

If you don't want to see any output at all from `open` then use this to redirect:

```
system 'open foo > /dev/null 2>&1'
=> false
```